Gift Aid Declaration With No Start Date
I made a payment for a purchase, stating that Gift Aid should not be claimed. I was interested to see what it would do to my declarations.
My existing Yes declaration still has no end date (I expected this to be updated).
There is a new No declaration with no dates at all (not even a start date of today).
I can't work out how any of this is going to be interpreted, and it doesn't seem right.
Is there an explanation?
